# Server shell backup script (bash)

Tags: bash, shell, backup, webfaction

Name of a script - `backup_script.sh`
Location of a script on server - `/home/company_folder/company_site_backups`

Line added to the cron file:

```
@monthly /home/company_folder/company_site_backups/backup_script.sh
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/home/company_folder/company_applications/*"
BACKUPDIR="/home/company_folder/company_site_backups"
NOW=`date +\%Y\%m\%d`
cd $DIR 
for i in $DIR; do zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$BACKUPDIR/$i-$NOW"; done 
ls -l 
echo "Done!"
```

But unfortunately my script does not work properly. Actually. It does not run at all! I do not see any errors in the syntax. 
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The `cd $DIR` seems strange; if the first entry found by `/home/company_folder/company_applications/*` is a directory it will change to that directory; if it is a file (or company_applications is empty) it will get an error.

Perhaps everything is running correctly except that because of the above your `ls -l` is not running in the directory you expect?  Try removing the `cd` and changing it to `ls -l $DIR`.

It also seems very strange to me that you are zipping up content *from* a backup directory into an applications directory.  Perhaps you meant to be doing:

```
zip -r "$BACKUPDIR/`basename $i`-$NOW" $i
```

Answer (score 0):

could you try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/home/company_folder/company_applications/*"
BACKUPDIR="/home/company_folder/company_site_backups"
NOW=`date +\%Y\%m\%d`
cd $DIR 
for i in $DIR
do
  base=$(basename "$i")
  zip -r $BACKUPDIR/$base-${NOW}.zip  $i
done
ls -l $BACKUPDIR
echo "Done!"
```